# How to add horizontal bars with jQuery flot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I would like to place multiple events on timeline. Is it possible to build chart with jQuery flot where I have multiple horizontal bars in same level and same color? http://prntscr.com/2pdwby

Answer (score 0):

This [Gantt plugin](http://jumflot.jumware.com/examples/Experimental/Gantt.html) is similar to what you're looking for.